# optgroup not viewable?

Tags: jquery, optgroup

Why is the optgroup here not viewable?

All options are shown, but not the group name

http://jsfiddle.net/UCNJ8/

```
$('<select></select>').appendTo('body').append('<option value="0">test</option>')
    .append($('<optgroup>group</optgroup>')
            .append('<option value="1">group test</option>'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The group name is set via the `label` attribute ([HTML4 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#edef-OPTGROUP)), not by its content (only `option` elements can be children of `optgroup` elements).

```
$('<optgroup />', {label: "group"})
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/UCNJ8/1/)